# Interactive image sequence iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ipad, animation

I am currently midway through building an iPad application, however would like to add an interactive image sequence.
I have tried using the built in animation functionality as below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 1; i < 359; i = i+3) {

    if(i < 10){
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"carredhub1_0000%d.png", i]]];
    }
    else if(i < 100){
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"carredhub1_000%d.png", i]]];
    }
    else if(i < 1000){
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"carredhub1_00%d.png", i]]];
    }

}

// Normal Animation
UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
animationImageView.animationImages = images;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 5.0;

[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
[animationImageView startAnimating];
```

However I cannot figure out how to manually control this. What I want is to be able to set which frame is animated too, for example a right swipe would move the animation on 50 frames and then the animation would sit is there a way I can set which frame number is the current frame and or set a stop frame(I do not want to increase the amount of frames cycled through in relation to velocity or length of swipe).

Any help is much appreciated, thanks, Will

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this using animationImages. Instead, you should use a timer to call setImage:, so you can proceed through your array however you want.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will have a look at different options!